# Get the file name for a document attached using AJAX on the JSP page

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a JSP form where in one of the field I am uploading a document, say a notepad using an AJAX call and the upload is happening in a UNIX path. Now I need to see the name of the attached document on the jsp once the upload is successful. Please let me know how can I do it.

Ajax Call:

```
         $.ajax({
           type : 'POST',
           url : '/test/actionToController/',
           data: new FormData(document.getElementById("formNameInJSP")),
           enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           async: false,
           success : function(result) {

           },
           error : function(result) {

               console.log('ohh.. something happened in Document Upload');
           }
        });
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/actionToController", headers=("content-    
    type=multipart/*"), method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String actionToController(@RequestParam("myFile")     
    CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload, HttpSession session)
    throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {


    /* Upload Code removed from here, its working fine */

    docName = notepadTest.txt;

    return "docName";
}
```

docName here has the name of the file which we need to see in the JSP page.

Thanks

Comment: You will get the response in the ajax success function, you have 'result' as a reponse there.

Comment: when I am returning docName from the action the code isn't working and the Ajax isn't getting response, when I am returning the name of the JSP page and then checking result in the AJAX call i am getting a jsp page